# How to install sending email plugin in WordPress?

Tags: email, wordpress

I want to add sending mass email functionality to my wordpress site. I don't know how to install and make the email plugin on wordpress?

Comment: Have you tried to google this one at least ?

Comment: Or at least reading the documentation that comes with the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Check this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mass-email-to-users/). Is just for you want!

Send email massive from your WP site.